# send email from openVMS

Tags: email, openvms

I am not familiar with OpenVMS but I would like to understand how to write a script that will send an email whenever I call it. My understanding is that the body of the email is put in a temp file before it is converted to text and sent. How do I create this file? Do you have any examples to write a script that will send an email like this?

```
From: blah@gmail.com
To: you@gmail.com
Subject: this is a body
Body:
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ temp = f$unique() + ".tmp"
$ open/write/error=error temp 'temp'
$ write temp "line1"
$ write temp "line2"
$ write temp "line3"
$ close temp
$ define/user tcpip$smtp_from "blah@gmail.com"
$ mail/subject="this is a body" 'temp' "you@gmail.com"
$ delete/nolog 'temp';*
$ goto exit
$error:
$ write sys$output "Unexpected error: " + f$message ($status)
$ goto exit
$exit:
$ exit
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send email from the command line:

```
$ mail/subject="this is a body" Sys$Input you@gmail.com
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
$ exit
```

Normally you would create a file to send first:

```
$ create MyMessage.txt
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
$ mail/subject="this is a body" MyMessage.txt you@gmail.com
$ delete MyMessage.txt;
```

Documentation is [here](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/731final/6489/6489pro_012.html).

Answer (score 1):

The answer that I saw includes the files into your body.

You maybe want to join a file... Here's how I attach a file in email:

```
$ UUENCODE my_file_to_attach.ext my_file_to_attach.ext
$ MAIL/SUBJECT="A subject..." my_file_to_attach.ext you@a_domain.com
$ DELETE my_file_to_attach.ext;
```

If you want to include a body:

```
$ CREATE temp.file
Hello,
    Here's the in attachment.
    Regards.
$ UUENCODE my_file_to_attach.ext my_file_to_attach.ext
$ TYPE my_file_to_attach.ext, temp.file physical_file_send.txt
$ MAIL/SUBJECT="A subject" physical_file_send.txt you@a_domain.com
$ DELETE physical_file_send.txt;, my_file_to_attach.ext;
```